# Change Color of Pair Plot Points by Column Value using Seaborn

Tags: seaborn

Using the iris data set and seaborn pair plot and the following code:

```
sns.pairplot(iris, hue="class", diag_kind = 'kde', markers=["o", "s", "D"])
```

Gives you something like this:

[image: Iris seaborn pair plot]

I'm trying to replicate this with another data set I'm working with. It's the monthly returns of four publicly traded companies: amzn, fb, ibm, mmm.

Data set looks like this:

```
              AMZN        IBM         MMM          FB
Date                
2016-04-29  0.072016    0.039741    0.030894    0.010415
2016-05-31  0.136702    0.000138    0.005589    0.058342
2016-06-30  0.027122    0.023761    0.014004    -0.026895
2016-07-29  0.035005    0.044894    0.051525    0.033821
2016-08-31  0.031521    0.022542    0.006572    0.044401
```

Any idea how I can simulate the look of the iris pairplot with the stock returns data plot? Right now I only get a single color and marker when I run the pair plot, but having different colors or markers to distinguish the returns of each stock would really make the pairs look cleaner.

**Update:**

I think the question here should actually be how can I transform the data so that there is a 'Stock' category and four entries on the same date period? It would look like this:

```
           Stock        Return
Date                
2016-04-29  AMZN      0.039741    
2016-04-29  IBM       0.000138    
2016-04-29  MMM       0.023761   
2016-04-29  FB        0.044894
```

I'm not sure this would work, but I think it would since there would be a category for 'hue'.

Comment: what is the category for the colors? from your dataframe, it looks like you want to show `sns.pairplot(df[['AMZN','IBM','MMM','FB']])`.

Comment: Correct. But the stocks are their own categories right now. I've updated the question because I think what I need to do is transform the df so that there is a new column called "Stock" which holds the value for AMZN, IBM, etc. And then a date for each return along that row.

Comment: Same problem of my answer. Now we've got a categorical data column you could use as `hue`, but we have only one values column, so you've got nothing to "pair", you need more than one values column to pair values and visually check for correlation. For example: Stock to use as category, Return and SomeOtherValue to plot.

Comment: @Player_1 sure, you can melt your original dataframe no problem. Post a sketch of what you want, with your data. Show us how these data can be both a pairplot and have hue colors; right now, it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In your DataFrame you have only columns of values but no column of categories, so you can't reproduce that pair plot because there is no category to use as `hue`.

Comment: Makes sense. I've updated my question to see if there's possibly another way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You have to first better define what are you searching for. You want to explore a correlation between what and what?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset does not have enough dimensions to be a pairplot *and* have hue color-coding. If you want a pairplot, you can just use Seaborn's pairplot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-04-29','2016-05-31','2016-06-30','2016-07-29','2016-08-31'],
                   'AMZN': [0.072016,0.136702,0.027122,0.035005,0.031521],
                   'IBM': [0.039741,0.000138,0.023761,0.044894,0.022542],
                   'MMM': [0.030894,0.005589,0.014004,0.051525,0.006572],
                   'FB': [0.010415,0.058342,-0.026895,0.033821,0.044401]
                   })


sns.pairplot(df[['AMZN','IBM','MMM','FB']])
plt.show()
```

[image]

If your question is "how to transform the data," then you can just do a melt:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Date').rename(columns={'variable': 'Stock'})
print(df2)
          Date Stock     value
0   2016-04-29  AMZN  0.072016
1   2016-05-31  AMZN  0.136702
2   2016-06-30  AMZN  0.027122
3   2016-07-29  AMZN  0.035005
4   2016-08-31  AMZN  0.031521
5   2016-04-29   IBM  0.039741
6   2016-05-31   IBM  0.000138
7   2016-06-30   IBM  0.023761
8   2016-07-29   IBM  0.044894
9   2016-08-31   IBM  0.022542
10  2016-04-29   MMM  0.030894
11  2016-05-31   MMM  0.005589
12  2016-06-30   MMM  0.014004
13  2016-07-29   MMM  0.051525
14  2016-08-31   MMM  0.006572
15  2016-04-29    FB  0.010415
16  2016-05-31    FB  0.058342
17  2016-06-30    FB -0.026895
18  2016-07-29    FB  0.033821
19  2016-08-31    FB  0.044401
```